# Compiling Python3 Project on Macbook. 'stdio.h' file not found error

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, bazel

I was trying to compile Python3 locust tests using bazel but was getting an error during compile. This was the main part of the error:

```
 Compiling with an SDK that doesn't seem to exist: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk
    Please check your Xcode installation
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk -g0 -Iext -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c ext/_parser.c -o build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.9/ext/_parser.o
    clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
    In file included from ext/_parser.c:2:
    /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/Python.h:25:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
    #include <stdio.h>
```

I'm compiling on a Macbook Pro (Intel) on Big Sur version 11.6.7.

Answer (score 0):

My solution feels super hacky, and I'll accept another answer if there's a more canonical solution. However, this seems to unblock me.

...

The error noted that the folder `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk` was missing. I checked the folder and found that it was indeed missing.

```
✗ ls /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/
MacOSX.sdk      MacOSX10.15.sdk MacOSX11.1.sdk
```

I did, however, see that the folder `MacOSX11.1.sdk` existed. So I made a symbolic link to that folder with the name requested in my build...

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/
sudo ln -s MacOSX11.1.sdk MacOSX11.sdk
```